# Nilpotent subgroups of the direct limit of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with arbitrarily large finite subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

We embeds $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ in $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb{Z})$ by identifying $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with $\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in GL_{n+1}(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $GL_\infty(\mathbb{Z})$ be the direct limit (or the union if you like) of all $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Then it is easy to see that the countable group $GL_\infty(\mathbb{Z})$ contains a copy of every finite group as one of its subgroups. My question is, given any $M > 0$, does there exist a *nilpotent infinite* subgroup $H$ of $G$, such that there exists a *finite* subgroup $K$ of $H$, with $\lvert K \rvert > M$? One can also ask the weaker question by replacing *nilpotent* with *solvable*.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the subgroup of all diagonal matrices?

Answer (score 1):

The "torus" $H<G$ consisting of diagonal matrices (with a finite number of $-1$-entries) is as required, as is any infinite direct sum of finite nilpotent groups of bounded index of nilpotency.